# Can I separat nginx, gunicorn and POSTGRES and put them on their own machines?

Tags: nginx, web-server, postgresql, django, gunicorn

I haven't been able able to get an answer to this question

I know that we can separate database from the application but can I separate nginx(web server) and gunicorn(application server) too?

first of all should I?
and secondly how to do it when you haven't started building your project and when you have (does this migration add extra complexity if you already of thousands of users already)

Thanks

Comment: Can you? Yes. Should you? Sure, if you need to for load or admin reasons. Or use containers. Whatever. For dev it doesn't matter in the slightest.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. As long as you use TCP connections and not UNIX sockets. Make sure to encrypt the connections if there is any sensitive data. Or use a VPN.

Comment: Hehe didn't get anything